# Need helping performing sentiment analysis on customer reviews and for a string of text

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis

This is a 2 part code question.

1.) Need to perform sentiment analysis on a csv file for customer reviews.

2.) Need to perform sentiment analysis on a harry potter book review saved as a .txt

1.) The name of this Dataframe is "reviews" and what I want to do is display the sentiment score for each of these 5 reviews under the "sent" column.  Thank you so much!!! If you can provide the code with the "sent" column filled  with its sentiment analysis score for each row that would be awesome!!

reviews.head()

```
 ID  Customer Name    Review                                       Sent  

 1   Jack             Beautiful cover up. My only 
                      feedback is that it is a tad larger 
                      than expected, but since it's a cover 
                      up, it doesn't need to be fitted. The 
                      waist tassels also allow you to adjust 
                      to fit your waist which is nice. 
                      Otherwise, its exactly as expected!

 2   Rachel           This tunic is very cute in person. It's 
                      more sheer than I'd like, but I imagine 
                      I'll wear it a ton on vacation.

 3   Ryan             Just got this sweet little dress in 
                      blue. It's a great little dress for a 
                      pool cover up. I can envision myself 
                      wearing it on our winter getaway for 
                      breakfast or on a walk. I'm not sure how 
                      see through it is. I think I could get 
                      away wearing it as a dress. The length 
                      is great, not too short. The quality is 
                      great. I got a size S. Fits true to size. 
                      I am usually a size 2, 34b, 129lb, slim 
                      build. Very happy with this.

 4   Jennifer         Love this hat! Kept the sun off my face 
                      and neck/chest in the intense tropical 
                      sun! Choose white - so I stayed cool.

 5   Alex             What I like about bikinis is that they 
                      always fit you perfectly. You won't 
                      realize how gorgeous they are and how 
                      attractive they make your body look 
                      until you put one on. As for the bra-part 
                      it gives good support and sits well. I 
                      also like the fabric: it stretches well 
                      without losing its shape, the color 
                      doesn't fade. This bikini is no exception. 
                      is far better at making bikinis than 
                      anybody else, I would say!
```

For this string I just to know what the overall sentiment score is... thanks!!

2.)

"Parents need to know that Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone is a thrill-a-minute story, the first in J.K. Rowling's Harry Potter series. It respects kids' intelligence and motivates them to tackle its greater length and complexity, play imaginative games, and try to solve its logic puzzles. It's the lightest in the series, but it still has some scary stuff for sensitive readers: a three-headed dog, an attacking troll, a violent life-size chess board, a hooded figure over a dead and bleeding unicorn, as well as a discussion of how Harry's parents died years ago."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please keep in mind for any further questions that stackoverflow is not a code writting service and you should always provide some code you have tried by yourself.

TextBlob is a python package which has a [sentiment analysis](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstart.html#sentiment-analysis) and returns you a polarity and subjectivity of a given text. To apply this sentiment analysis function to your dataframe you need to use the corrospondent function [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Have a look at the example below:

```py
import pandas as pd
from textblob import TextBlob

df = pd.DataFrame([['1',   'Jack',    "Beautiful cover up. My only feedback is that it is a tad larger than expected, but since it's a cover up, it doesn't need to be fitted. The waist tassels also allow you to adjust to fit your waist which is nice. Otherwise, its exactly as expected!"],
['2',   'Rachel',  "This tunic is very cute in person. It's more sheer than I'd like, but I imagine I'll wear it a ton on vacation."],
['3',   'Ryan',    "Just got this sweet little dress in blue. It's a great little dress for a pool cover up. I can envision myself wearing it on our winter getaway for breakfast or on a walk. I'm not sure how see through it is. I think I could get away wearing it as a dress. The length is great, not too short. The quality is great. I got a size S. Fits true to size. I am usually a size 2, 34b, 129lb, slim build. Very happy with this."],
['4',   'Jennifer',    "Love this hat! Kept the sun off my face and neck/chest in the intense tropical sun! Choose white - so I stayed cool."],
['5',   'Alex',   "What I like about bikinis is that they always fit you perfectly. You won't realize how gorgeous they are and how attractive they make your body look until you put one on. As for the bra-part it gives good support and sits well. I also like the fabric: it stretches well without losing its shape, the color doesn't fade. This bikini is no exception. is far better at making bikinis than anybody else, I would say!"]], columns=['ID',  'CustomerName',   'Review'] )


df['sent'] = df['Review'].apply(lambda x:  TextBlob(x).sentiment)
#you can get the polarity and subjectivty values in separate columns by splitting
df['polarity'] =  df['sent'].str[0]
df['subjectivity'] =  df['sent'].str[1]
```

Regarding your second question, just execute the following:

```py
TextBlob("Parents need to know that Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone is a thrill-a-minute story, the first in J.K. Rowling's Harry Potter series. It respects kids' intelligence and motivates them to tackle its greater length and complexity, play imaginative games, and try to solve its logic puzzles. It's the lightest in the series, but it still has some scary stuff for sensitive readers: a three-headed dog, an attacking troll, a violent life-size chess board, a hooded figure over a dead and bleeding unicorn, as well as a discussion of how Harry's parents died years ago.").sentiment
```

Comment: do you have a clever way of separating polarity and subjectivity into separate columns?

Comment: @BenjaminBrown: I have modified my answer to address this. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have made a similar project on this in java as well as javascript

1. you can run it "https://sentimentanalyservibhor.000webhostapp.com/"
2. git repo: just extract and run index.html
   https://github.com/dev-vibhor/SentimentAnalysis_JavaScript/blob/master/SentimentAnalysisJS.zip
3. for analyzing different fields I have used n-gram algorithm
      "https://sentimentanalyservibhor.000webhostapp.com/ngram.html"
4. ngram git repo : 
   https://github.com/dev-vibhor/SentimentAnalysis_JavaScript/blob/master/index.html

   Bi Gram Implementation using JavaScript (N-GRAM)

   ---

   N-grams of texts are extensively used in text mining and natural language processing tasks. They are basically a set of co-occurring  words within a given window and when computing the n-grams you typically move one word forward (although you can move X words forward in more advanced scenarios). For example, for the sentence "The cow jumps over the moon". If N=2 (known as bi-grams), then the n-grams would be:

   > the cow
   >   cow jumps
   >   jumps over
   >   over the
   >   the moon

   ---

   for example:
   text= the hotel food was good

   If N=3(TRI-GRAM) and keyword== food

   I will get a result as

   1. the hotel food  : neutral , discard it
   2. food was good   : positive

the overall sentiment of keyword 'food'=positive

youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qMe8wB8sOds

mail: vibsin95@outlook.com